# Detecting deleted records LINQ Except - Local sequence cannot be used

Tags: linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

I have a WCF service which receives an

```
ObservableCollection<Pouch> colPouchDetails;
```

I'm trying to delete all records in the DB that are not contained in this ObservableCollection (based on the ID column):

```
var deletedPouches = DB.Pouches.Except(colPouchDetails);
```

"This throws Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator"

How can I get the colPouchDetails ID field in an IQueryable or IEnumerable so that I know what has been deleted from the original list? Once I get this list, I can loop through it deleting each record from the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Select(d => d.ID)` to get collection of `ID`s, and call `Contains` on that collection, as error message states.

Because you need all items which do not have corresponding element in `colPouchDetails`, you have to negate the `Contains` method result using `!` negation operator.

```
var deletedPouches = DB.Pouches.Where(p => !colPouchDetails.Select(d => d.ID)
                                                           .Contains(p.ID))
```